# How to group the second elements of multiple nested arrays based on first element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The first Array is something like this :

```
let firstArray = [[0,2], [1,3], [0,5], [2,8], [1,4], [3,2]];
```

I want to merge the nested arrays that has the same first element and use that first element as index in the new built array ; the resulted array should be something like this:

```
secondArray = [[2,5], [3,4], [8], [2]]
```

what is the best way to achieve this in javascript .

Comment: Generally you'd use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to transform an array into a new structure but your expected result doesn't match your requirements. Shouldn't there be an `undefined` or `null` entry for index 3?

Comment: @Phil Thanks , i fixed the question for index 3 . i will look into the Array.prototype.reduce() you suggested .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array to produce the desired result like this

```js
let firstArray = [[0,2], [1,3], [0,5], [2,8], [1,4], [4,2]];

const secondArray = firstArray.reduce((acc, [ idx, val ]) => {
  acc[idx] = acc[idx] ?? [] // initialise to an empty array
  acc[idx].push(val) // add the value
  return acc
}, []).filter(Boolean) // filter skipped indices

console.log(JSON.stringify(secondArray))
```

I've added in a [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove skipped indices.